# scrapy returning too many rows in tables

Tags: python, scrapy

Feels like I'm not grasping some concepts here, or trying to fly before I can crawl (pun intended).

There are indeed 5 tables on the page, with the one I'm interested in being the 3rd. But executing this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# python 3.x

import sys
import os
import re
import requests
import scrapy

class iso3166_spider( scrapy.Spider):
  name = "countries"

  def start_requests( self):
    urls = ["https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1"]
    for url in urls:
      yield scrapy.Request( url=url, callback=self.parse) 

  def parse( self, response):
    title = response.xpath('//title/text()').get()
    print("-- title -- {0}".format(title))
    list_table_selector = response.xpath('//table')   # gets all tables on page
    print("-- table count -- {0}".format( len( list_table_selector)))
    table_selector = response.xpath('//table[2]')     # inspect to figure out which one u want
    table_selector_text = table_selector.getall()     # got the right table, starts with Afghanistan
#   print( table_selector_text)
#
#   here is where things go wrong
    list_row_selector = table_selector.xpath('//tr')
    print("number of rows in table: {0}".format( len( list_row_selector)))  # gives 302, should be close to 247
    for i in range(0,20):
      row_selector = list_row_selector[i]
      row_selector_text = row_selector.getall()
      print("i={0}, getall:{1}".format(i, row_selector_text)
```

prints the getall() of each row in EVERY table - I see the row for Afghanistan as row 8 not row 2

Changing

```
    list_row_selector = table_selector.xpath('//tr')
```

to

```
    list_row_selector = table_selector.xpath('/tr')
```

results in zero rows found where I'd expect roughly 247

Ultimately I want the name and three codes for each country, should be straightforward.

What am I doing wrong?

TIA,

kerchunk

Comment: I find your question code a bit confusing, but you may be looking for `.//tr`.

Comment: EUREKA!!! That was it - the lack of a single period .  Thx!  CASE CLOSED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tbl = response.xpath("//th[starts-with(text(),'English short name')]/ancestor::table/tbody/tr[position()>1]") # try this xpath. I check the source of web page, the header ("th" elements) line is under tbody also.
```

You can also try to replace "//tr" with ".//tr"

Comment: You and Gallaecio are both correct, my code needed only a "." in a specific place. If he replies with an Answer instead of a Comment I could give him the credit.